# Mockito - mock a method call in constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class `X` which takes in a `YBuilder` and constructs an instance of `Y`

```
public class X {
  private Y y;
  public X(YBuilder builder) throws IOException{
    y = builder.build();
  }
}
```

I need to mock all calls to `Y`, so I have written my Unit tests like this:

```
@Mock
private Y Y;

@Mock
private YBuilder builder;

@InjectMocks
private X x;

@Before
public void setup() {
  when(builder.build()).thenReturn(y); // this does not work
}
```

I get a `Null Pointer Exception` in my main class since the dependency `Y` has not been mocked.

I think this is due to the fact that `@InjectMocks` instantiates a new instance of `X` before I am able to mock the call.

How can I fix this? Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: This code won't compile. Your YBuilder class returns a Y, not an X.

Comment: @fge I made a mistake while writing the code here. Changed it to return a y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, ok - the issue here is that the code `y = builder.build()` is called in the constructor of `X`, before `when(builder.build()).thenReturn(y)` is ever set up.

Do you have control over class X? If so, are you able to store a reference to the builder in X, and call `.build()` later?

```
public class X {
    private YBuilder builder;
    public X(YBuilder builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
    }
}
```

Otherwise it might be most straightforward to initialize the mocks manually in the `setup()` method.

Comment: I do have control over `class X` but I need the builder once to create instance of `Y`. So it does not add value by storing an instance of builder. Explicit initialization of mocks seems to do the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you think something is happening then prove it with the code. You can remove the observed behavior and construct `X` yourself:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
  when(builder.build()).thenReturn(y); // this does not work
  x = new X(builder);
}
```

If this works then you have validated your concern and can move on in your testing.

Comment: This works. But is this the correct way to initialize the class in `@Before`?